# I want to play Dr. Manhattan. How can I?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation

How can I create a character that is powerful like Dr. Manhattan?

The critical thematic elements are that he:

- is composed of energy
- uses pure energy as a power source

Either one of these are the mechanical effects I want:

1. Not engaging in physical combat, but simply waving a finger and destroying stuff in my way.
2. Able to create matter at will.

Of course both would be ideal, but if it cannot be done then one is enough. Flying or hovering is not mechanically important, but would be a nice bonus. All D&D 3.5e books and sources allowed, including homebrew.

We are starting at 1st level. If this isn't possible at 1st level, how to build toward it during play is an OK alternative.

Comment: So...it's your first D&D game, and you want to be all-powerful at level 1?

Comment: This is all just themes, the concept. Also its not my first dnd game, its just the first of the new campaign.
Dr. Manhattan was a suggestion, the floating is just fluff, but the rest is themes for builds, and dont forget homebrew is ok

Comment: What level is your group starting at? (Or is this a theoretical exercise you're doing on your own and level isn't limited?)

Comment: 1st level, but aiming for something thats a higher level is fine aswell

Comment: This eddit better? SevenSideDie helped

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21133/discussion-on-question-by-simon-i-want-to-play-dr-manhattan-how-can-i).

Answer (score 2):

To tamper with the "soul", to disintegrate matter with a thought: psionics. This character won't be amazingly *powerful*, but will be iconic to what you're going for. You get a natural "melee touch attack" that does 1d6 points of damage, and can certainly be visualised as an attack on a creature's soul.

Unfortunately, you'll need to use the creature progressions in savage species to be able to start out as this character at level 1, as an unbodied has 4HD as well as a +4 LA, but given your group is OK with house rules, it just means breaking the build up into a standard progression.

Then, continue with psion normally until you can dip briefly into soul eater, simply such that your touch also bestows negative levels (and for other flavour reasons.)

To do this at level one, become Pun Pun, then do the above.